# Dealing with singularity in lmer (r = 1) when the estimated variance is high

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a genuine question about singular (linear mixed) models and would appreciate any help.

In my study, I am trying to predict people's emotion perception responses based on who the target expressing the emotion is (**variable Group**: social ingroup/outgroup member) and based on the response 'level' (**variable Condition_Cat**: First-order - The person is giving a response for themselves; Second-order ingroup - The person is guessing how other ingroup members would perceive the same emotion; Second-order outgroup - The person is guessing how outgroup members would perceive the same emotion).

All my fixed effects are research question-driven, but random effects are not, and that's where the question pops up. I started with the maximal model and simplified it further to find a non-singular structure, so I am currently fitting this model:

```
EP_model <- lmer(EmotionPerception ~ Group * Condition_Cat + (1 + Condition_Cat|Participant) + (1 + Group|Stimulus)
```

With the participant random structure, I have run into the following scenario:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: EmotionPerception ~ Group * Condition_Cat + (1 + Condition_Cat | Participant.Public.ID) + (1 + Group | TextClean)
   Data: subset(DataFinalOutliers, DataFinalOutliers$EmotionPerceptionOut == FALSE)

REML criterion at convergence: 67279.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.5090 -0.4963  0.1080  0.6267  4.0512 

Random effects:
 Groups                Name                        Variance Std.Dev. Corr      
 Participant.Public.ID (Intercept)                  68.372   8.269             
                       Condition_CatSecondOrderCro  21.496   4.636   0.42      
                       Condition_CatSecondOrderSrb  27.368   5.231   0.34  1.00
 TextClean             (Intercept)                  37.974   6.162             
                       GroupSerbian                  1.615   1.271   -0.11     
 Residual                                          133.942  11.573             
Number of obs: 8584, groups:  Participant.Public.ID, 184; TextClean, 16

Fixed effects:
                                          Estimate Std. Error        df t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                84.7811     1.6850   20.8305  50.315 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
GroupSerbian                                0.3468     0.5387   43.4388   0.644              0.52312    
Condition_CatSecondOrderCro                -4.2798     0.5510  402.8621  -7.768   0.0000000000000669 ***
Condition_CatSecondOrderSrb                -6.8358     0.5800  346.7130 -11.786 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
GroupSerbian:Condition_CatSecondOrderCro   -2.7937     0.6125 8190.6376  -4.561   0.0000051589586650 ***
GroupSerbian:Condition_CatSecondOrderSrb    1.7204     0.6132 8192.9136   2.806              0.00504 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) GrpSrb C_CSOC C_CSOS GS:C_CSOC
GroupSerbin -0.164                               
Cndtn_CtSOC -0.006  0.316                        
Cndtn_CtSOS -0.016  0.300  0.705                 
GrpS:C_CSOC  0.091 -0.573 -0.552 -0.264          
GrpS:C_CSOS  0.091 -0.572 -0.278 -0.526  0.503   
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

The correlation of 1 is between different levels of the same random slope (Condition_Cat), but the estimated variance is still reasonably high.

The output of rePCA is the following:

```
$Participant.Public.ID
Importance of components:
                         [,1]   [,2]       [,3]
Standard deviation     0.7841 0.5104 0.00001497
Proportion of Variance 0.7024 0.2976 0.00000000
Cumulative Proportion  0.7024 1.0000 1.00000000

$TextClean
Importance of components:
                         [,1]    [,2]
Standard deviation     0.5326 0.10907
Proportion of Variance 0.9597 0.04025
Cumulative Proportion  0.9597 1.00000
```

Finally, the output of a model with uncorrelated intercept and slope is the following:

```
REML criterion at convergence: 67279.8

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.5090 -0.4964  0.1080  0.6267  4.0512 

Random effects:
 Groups                  Name                        Variance      Std.Dev.  Corr      
 Participant.Public.ID   (Intercept)                   0.000002478  0.001574           
 Participant.Public.ID.1 Condition_CatFirstOrder      68.367801037  8.268482           
                         Condition_CatSecondOrderCro 122.318002235 11.059747 0.93      
                         Condition_CatSecondOrderSrb 124.738596686 11.168643 0.90  1.00
 TextClean               (Intercept)                  37.958002021  6.161007           
                         GroupSerbian                  1.613997847  1.270432 -0.11     
 Residual                                            133.941486943 11.573309           
Number of obs: 8584, groups:  Participant.Public.ID, 184; TextClean, 16

Fixed effects:
                                          Estimate Std. Error        df t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                84.7811     1.6847   20.8453  50.324 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
GroupSerbian                                0.3468     0.5386   43.4729   0.644              0.52308    
Condition_CatSecondOrderCro                -4.2798     0.5510  402.7337  -7.767   0.0000000000000671 ***
Condition_CatSecondOrderSrb                -6.8358     0.5800  346.6410 -11.785 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
GroupSerbian:Condition_CatSecondOrderCro   -2.7937     0.6125 8190.6462  -4.561   0.0000051588183409 ***
GroupSerbian:Condition_CatSecondOrderSrb    1.7204     0.6132 8192.9224   2.806              0.00504 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) GrpSrb C_CSOC C_CSOS GS:C_CSOC
GroupSerbin -0.164                               
Cndtn_CtSOC -0.006  0.316                        
Cndtn_CtSOS -0.016  0.300  0.705                 
GrpS:C_CSOC  0.091 -0.573 -0.552 -0.264          
GrpS:C_CSOS  0.091 -0.572 -0.278 -0.526  0.503   
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

My question is what does one do in this situation where the singularity is coming from the slope itself (so I cannot just remove the correlation between the intercept and the slope), but the estimated variance is not negligible? Would this still point to potential over-fitting and should this slope be dropped?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please include the full output from `summary(EP_model)`

Comment: Also, does `lmer` actually report that the model is singular ? Use `isSingular(EP_model)` to be sure.

Comment: Hi @RobertLong, thank you for replying! I have posted the full summary above, and yes, the model is labelled as singular (isSingular also gives TRUE)

Comment: You're welcome. Let's try to diagnose the problem. Can you add the output of `summary(rePCA(EP_model))` and then also the output of the same model but with  `(Condition_Cat||Participant)` instead of `(Condition_Cat|Participant)`

Comment: Added both! Both the estimated variance and the inter-level correlations are now higher than before, and the model is still labelled as singular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the model is singular and principal components analysis on the variance covariance matrix of random effects shows that 100% of the variance is accounted for by the first two variance components in the `Participant` grouping.

This leads us to remove the random slopes variable from the `Participant`:

```
lmer(EmotionPerception ~ Group * Condition_Cat + (1 |Participant) + (1 + Group|Stimulus)
```

I expect that this model will converge without singularity.

---

Edit: To take this further you could replace the `Condition_Cat` variable with dummy variables. I have simulated some data, with the same problem as in the OP, and including a categorical variable with 3 levels also as in the OP, to show how this can be done:

```
set.seed(217)
dt <- expand.grid(F = c("A","B","C"), G = 1:10, reps = 1:2)
X <- model.matrix(~ F, dt)  # model matrix for fixed effects

dt$Y <- 1
myFormula <- "Y ~ F + (F | G)"
foo <- lFormula(eval(myFormula), dt)
Z <- t(as.matrix(foo$reTrms$Zt))  # model matrix for random effects

betas <- c(11, 1, 1)   # fixed effects

b <- rnorm(dim(Z)[2])  # random effects

# simulate the response using the mixed model equation
dt$Y <- X %*% betas + Z %*% b + rnorm(nrow(dt))

summary(m0 <- lmer(myFormula, dt))

##  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr       
##  G        (Intercept) 1.4495   1.2040              
##           FB          0.6918   0.8317   -0.40      
##           FC          1.3070   1.1432   -0.37  1.00
##  Residual             0.6546   0.8090
```

So we have the same problem as in the OP: a correlation between the random slopes of 1, while the variances seem comfortably greater than zero.

Now we create a new dataframe using the model matrix `X` which already has the dummy variables, and fit the model:

```
dt1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(X, dt$Y, dt$G))
names(dt1)[1] <- "Intercept"
names(dt1)[4:5] <- c("Y","G")

summary(lmer(Y ~ -1  + Intercept + FB + FC + (FB + FC | G), data = dt1))

## Random effects:
##  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr       
##  G        (Intercept) 1.4495   1.2040              
##           FB          0.6918   0.8317   -0.40      
##           FC          1.3070   1.1432   -0.37  1.00
##  Residual             0.6546   0.8090
```

Note that we specify no fixed intercept because the data already contains a column of 1s named "Intercept". As expected this is the same as above (since it's the same model). But now we can remove the correlations between the random effects and see what happens:

```
summary(lmer(Y ~ -1  + Intercept + FB + FC + (FB + FC || G), data = dt1))

##  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
##  G        (Intercept) 1.1954   1.0934  
##  G.1      FB          0.0000   0.0000  
##  G.2      FC          0.3430   0.5856  
##  Residual             0.8322   0.9122
```

This model is still singular but now we see that the estimated variance for `FB` is zero. So now we remove that random slope for `FB`

```
summary(lmer(Y ~ -1  + Intercept + FB + FC + (FC | G), data = dt1))

## Random effects:
##  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
##  G        (Intercept) 1.1725   1.0828       
##           FC          0.3255   0.5705   0.09
##  Residual             0.8352   0.9139
```

...and the model converges normally.